# python selenium PhantomJS don't find element, but Firefox could

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://open.qq.com/login?from=http%3A%2F%2Fop.open.qq.com%2F')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.switch_to.frame('login_frame')
driver.find_element_by_id('u').send_keys('157447865')
driver.find_element_by_id('p').send_keys('abc_123_')
driver.find_element_by_id('login_button').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-manage')[1].click()
time.sleep(5)
app_num = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').text
driver.quit()

if app_num:
    day_total = app_num.split('\n')[0].split()
    return day_total[-3].replace(',', ''), day_total[-2].replace(',', '')
return '', '0'
```

when I ececute code 'driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-manage')[1]', driver can't tag name that class_name is 'btn-manage', which in fact have two element.why find element by driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-manage') in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-manage'), but Firefox could.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the catch.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('login_button').click() 
#are you sure you have logged in successfully under PhantomJS?
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-manage')[1].click()
```